# can geoserver select one of many rasters from a postgis table

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver

I have a postgis table with many different rasters in it. Is it possible for geoserver to grab only one of the rasters from the table based on something like a where clause?

Comment: You can try to build a view. http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: First, since I'm storing rasters in the postgis table, I'm using geoserver's Image Mosaic JDBC as per this link [postgis raster](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/data/raster/postgisraster.html). Second, when using Image Magic JDBC, the option to "Configure new SQL view..." isn't available. Instead I'm only presented with the link "Configure new Coverage view..." which is something [completely different](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/data/raster/coverageview.html).

Comment: It should work simply by adding an attribute (for example YEAR) into your image mosaic table and then adding into GetMaps `&CQL_FILTER=YEAR=2015`

Comment: @user30184 When you say add a YEAR attribute to the "image mosaic table" do you mean there just needs to be a column called 'YEAR' in my raster table... ie rid, rast, YEAR or is there another place I need to specify YEAR so that geoserver knows about it? I have another table called mosaic that has columns name, tiletable, minx, miny, maxx, maxy, resx, resy - year doesn't need to be added to that table does it?

Comment: I have not done this myself, but the "mosaic" table is what I meant. If you add YEAR or any other attribute into that it should be possible to filter the "granules" with CQL_FILTER. In this question column named "UUID" was used with success http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/image-mosaic-custom-dimension-to-select-raster-images-from-their-footprints-td5222046.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the code quickly, I believe that the GeoTools ImageMosaic JDBC module has no filtering abilities whatsoever.

Comment: In that case, If I have a raster per day of the year over many years what's the best way to serve them through geoserver? I could save each raster as a geotif file and then use [this method](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_geotiff.html) However because I'm spanning years 1980-present that will create thousands of stores/layers which doesn't seem right.

Comment: As said in the other ticket, use the plain imagemosaic reader, that's fully dimension enabled.